# Datafield 4 value incase of OMR currency

Tags: authorization, iso8583

I need help,

I want to send an Authorization of 315.85 OMR, what values should be sent in Datafield 4?

Answer (score 0):

DE 4 doesn't carry any currency implications so you should be able to represent that amount simply as **000000031585**. DE49(Transaction Currency Code) is the field that carries the **ISO 4217**-standard decimilization instruction. In your case, [**OMR**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omani_rial) would be the value of that field. Your transaction switch should be able to process the field appropriately

Answer (score 0):

DE004 is the local currency amount, so it would be the local OMR value.
DE049 would be set to the local currency amount is ISO-4217 Numeric ("512" not "OMR").

If you need to represent it in cardholder settlement currency amount you would then use DE005 or DE006 depending on the specification to represent it in their currency (i.e. US Dollars) and include the ISO-4217 numeric code in DE050. Currency conversion also has other supporting fields like DE009 & DE010 (Conversion Rates) along with DE016 that has currency conversion date.

Note I 'believe' the ISO-3166-3 Numeric has the same numeric value set as ISO-4217 as well if a local currency exists.  So if say Panama used US dollars the DE019 would be "590" but the currency code would be "840" (US).

Christopher